# How is this image encoded in a SQL Server database?

Tags: sql-server, image, encoding

The string below is an image stored in a SQL Server database table. It is encoded as a safe string just with alphanumeric chars. I would like to know it is encoded. My aim is to display it inside a web page, maybe with a data url. All the images in this column start with 0xFF.

```
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
```

Tip 1: the image was probably stored this way in a SQL Server 2000 database. 
Tip 2: it was exported from the original database just making a select into a grid output and selecting save as .csv.

Comment: The `image` data type is just a binary field, you're just looking at a simple way to display binary data. (though it's now `varbinary` as `image` has been deprecated)

Comment: @DavidG: But how do I convert it to a displayable format?

Comment: Well that depends on what language you're using.

Comment: Is this really stored as a **string** (column type `VARCHAR` or `NVARCHAR` or do you *think* this is a string and it is a BLOB actually (column type IMAGE, (N)TEXT (both deprecated!!!) or VARBINARY)?

Comment: @Shnugo: I dropped it to a csv file. I don't know the type in the database. I'll test it tomorrow.

Comment: @neves, When you do a `SELECT` on a binary column, it will be presented to you as a hex-string. This content must be *translated* into a human readable format to show up on screen So I'm pretty sure, that the actual column is not a string type... Anyway, my answer covers both possibilities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your value is `VARBINARY` you go like this:

```
DECLARE @YourImg VARBINARY(MAX)=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

SELECT 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + CAST((SELECT @YourImg FOR XML PATH('')) AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS [@src]
FOR XML PATH('img');
GO
```

Assuming your column is `IMAGE` or `TEXT` you would need a `CAST(MyValue AS VARBINARY(MAX))` first.

And if your value is a string, as you state it here (but I don't really believe this): *It is encoded as a safe string just with alphanumeric chars*, you might use a function like this [found it here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/e94011f4-ad7c-4fc0-be63-722d6799ee66/converting-a-hex-string-to-binary?forum=transactsql)

```
--https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/e94011f4-ad7c-4fc0-be63-722d6799ee66/converting-a-hex-string-to-binary?forum=transactsql
create function dbo.fn_hexstrtovarbin(@input varchar(8000)) 
  returns varbinary(8000) 
as 
begin 
 declare @result varbinary(8000), @i int, @l int 
  set @result = 0x 
  set @l = len(@input)/2 
  set @i = 2 
  while @i <= @l 
  begin 
    set @result = @result + 
      cast(cast(case lower(substring(@input, @i*2-1, 1)) 
        when '0' then 0x00 
        when '1' then 0x10 
        when '2' then 0x20 
        when '3' then 0x30 
        when '4' then 0x40 
        when '5' then 0x50 
        when '6' then 0x60 
        when '7' then 0x70 
        when '8' then 0x80 
        when '9' then 0x90 
        when 'a' then 0xa0 
        when 'b' then 0xb0 
        when 'c' then 0xc0 
        when 'd' then 0xd0 
        when 'e' then 0xe0 
        when 'f' then 0xf0 
      end as tinyint) | 
      cast(case lower(substring(@input, @i*2, 1)) 
        when '0' then 0x00 
        when '1' then 0x01 
        when '2' then 0x02 
        when '3' then 0x03 
        when '4' then 0x04 
        when '5' then 0x05 
        when '6' then 0x06 
        when '7' then 0x07 
        when '8' then 0x08 
        when '9' then 0x09 
        when 'a' then 0x0a 
        when 'b' then 0x0b 
        when 'c' then 0x0c 
        when 'd' then 0x0d 
        when 'e' then 0x0e 
        when 'f' then 0x0f 
      end as tinyint) as binary(1)) 
    set @i = @i + 1 
  end 
  return @result 
end 
go
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Shnugo. Almost there. The image is really stored as a image column in sql server.  I've never used this FOR XML feature. I'm acessing a table and would like to have the base64 returned as a row in a query, but I'm not able to do it. How I would make a query in sql server and have it returned as base64 encoded?

Comment: Got it: just have to make `(select [my_column_name] as '*' for xml path(''))` and to present it make an `<a src="data:image/jpeg;base64,@my_column_name">`

Answer (score 1):

Base64 encode the binary version (converted from the hex version as you provided in the example) of the image and set the img src to "data:image/jpeg;base64,[the encoded image]".
For the example that would be

```html
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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" />
```

Comment: hex encoding looks likes every two chars are an hex number. Is there an easy way to convert it to base64 in javascript?

Comment: Did you remove the 0x at the beginning? In the varbinary it is stored in its binary form already the 0x is just a representation detail of the csv dump.